# perf kvm report unknown

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, perf

I use perf in ubuntu 13.04 servier. kernel 3.8.0-19-generic.
And I run a virtual machine in kvm using the same os.

I want to profile guest os from the host side.
So I follow the guidance and do the following steps:

1. copy /proc/modules and /proc/kallsyms from the vm
2. perf kvm --guest --guestmodules=guest-modules --guestkallsyms=guest-kallsyms record -a
3. perf kvm --guest --guestmodules=guest-modules --guestkallsyms=guest-kallsyms report

But the output of the report is unknown

```
   97.33%  [guest/17599]  [unknown]         [g] 0xffffffff816d4470                
    2.67%  [guest/17599]  [unknown]         [u] 0x00007fe66f2f88fb
```

why the output is unknown? Using perf kvm top will have similar output.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but I have faced a similar problem recently. After doing some research, I have identified some reasons why you get [unknown] symbols while profiling guest VM from the host.

When you do a

`perf kvm --guest <guestkallsyms> <guestmodules> record -a`

from the host, the guest kernel will produce **PERF_RECORD_MMAPs** and **PERF_RECORD_FORK** etc. records which indicate guest binaries being mmapped to the guest memory and any process being forked and subsequently being exec'd (with **PERF_RECORD_COMM**).

These are sideband events generated by the kernel on the guest. While  recording from the host, the host obviously does not have access to the guest kernel ring-buffers for recording such PERF events. Note that these sideband events later become useful when one tries to identify context switches.

Any such events being generated by the **guest kernel** will be lost to the host and hence the host will fail to track the **guest binaries** being forked and mmapped. These `[unknown symbols]` represent the guest binaries obviously being missed from the host.

One approach that could probably be tried upon to solve this problem could be to build a **shared ring-buffer** between the guest and the host. This could be really complicated. Another approach could be to somehow synchronize the guest and host clocks and then run `perf record -a` on both the guest and host simultaneously. Later the two `perf.data` files could be merged to get the final result.

Note that any `perf` events being generated by the hardware (not kernel) on the guest will be available on the host too.. (like **PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE**). So it is likely that recording and post-processing with these events will work.